# Can't change background color of java application

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane, jviewport

I'm trying my hand at making a picture viewer in Java and for the life of me, I can't get the background color of the viewer to change to black.  Here's my latest code:

```
public class PictureViewer extends JFrame {
    static class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            pauseViewer = !pauseViewer;
        }
    }

    static class QuitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stopViewer = true;
            pauseViewer = true;
            viewer.setNextToView();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static Double height;
    static final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    static boolean pauseViewer = false;
    static Dimension screensize = new Dimension();
    static boolean stopViewer = false;
    static PictureViewer viewer;
    static Double width;

    JLabel area = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
    int currentPic = 0;
    File dir = new File(".");
    BufferedImage image;    
    String path;
    Action pauseAction;
    int pauseTime = 5;
    Action quitAction;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area,  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    ArrayList<File> thesePictures;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Create and set up the window.
        viewer = new PictureViewer();
        viewer.setUndecorated(true);  //Remove the minimize, maximize and close buttons entirely.

        //Get the list of files to display.
        viewer.initialize();

        //Set up the content pane.
        viewer.addComponents();
        viewer.setPreferredSize(screensize);

        //Display the window.
        viewer.pack();
        viewer.setVisible(true);

        //Start showing pictures.
        while (!stopViewer) {
            try {
                viewer.showPictures();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Perform cleanup
        viewer.setNextToView();
    }

    public void addComponents() {
        //Set up actions.
        pauseAction = new PauseAction();
        quitAction = new QuitAction();
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "doPauseAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doPauseAction", pauseAction);
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doQuitAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doQuitAction", quitAction);
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        viewer.repaint();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getPictures(File dir) {
        ArrayList<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
        int selectThis = (int) (Math.random() * listFiles.size());
        boolean emptyList = true;

        if (listFiles.get(selectThis).isDirectory()) {
            return getPictures(listFiles.get(selectThis));
        } else {
            //if the selected file is not a directory, go through the list of files and remove any directories.

            ArrayList<File> newList = new ArrayList<File>();

            for (File thisFile : listFiles) {
                if (!thisFile.isDirectory() && !thisFile.getName().contains(".next") && !thisFile.getName().contains(".jar")) {
                    newList.add(thisFile);
                }
            }

            listFiles = newList;
        }

        return listFiles;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        height = screensize.getHeight();
        width = screensize.getWidth();
        String filePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        filePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.length() - 1);
        String directory = "";

        while (thesePictures == null || thesePictures.size() == 0) {
            thesePictures = getPictures(dir);
        }

        String absolutePath = thesePictures.get(0).getAbsolutePath();
        path = absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));

        //Look to see if the .next file exists.  If so, read in the file object.  If not, set the index to 0.
        File checkFile = new File(path + "\\.next");

        if (checkFile.exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(path + "\\.next");
                InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(inputFile);
                ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
                File lastViewedPic = (File) input.readObject();

                if (thesePictures.contains(lastViewedPic)) {
                    currentPic = thesePictures.indexOf(lastViewedPic);
                } else {
                    currentPic = 0;
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Look at " + path + "\\.next");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        } else {
            currentPic = 0;
        }
    }

    public void readInFile(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.isFile()) {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(file);

                if (image.getWidth() > width || image.getHeight() > height) {
                    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width.intValue(), height.intValue(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width.intValue(), height.intValue(), null);
                    g.dispose();
                    image = newImage;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessageDialog(viewer,"Does not compute !","No file read or found",INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showMessageDialog(viewer, "Problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setImage(JLabel area){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        area.setIcon(icon);
        viewer.repaint();
    }

    protected void setNextToView() {
        //See if the next picture to view file exists.  If not, create it.
        File checkFile = new File(path + "\\.next");

        if (!checkFile.exists()) {
            try {
                checkFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\.next");
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(outputFile);
            writer.writeObject(thesePictures.get(currentPic));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showPictures() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!pauseViewer) {
            //If we reach the last file in the directory, switch to another directory (it could be the same directory).
            if (currentPic + 1 == thesePictures.size()) {
                currentPic = 0;
                thesePictures = new ArrayList<File>();

                while (thesePictures == null || thesePictures.size() == 0) {
                    thesePictures = getPictures(dir);
                }
            } else {
                currentPic += 1;
            }

            readInFile(thesePictures.get(currentPic).getAbsolutePath());
            setImage(area);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(pauseTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Just what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the rest of your class. I suspect that you're sizing `scrollPane` to cover up the entire background, leaving the content pane obscured, but it's hard to tell without seeing all the declarations and your whole UI construction.

Comment: This is a bit too much... Try making a simpler example, and add pieces until it starts misbehaving. That's a useful debugging technique.

Comment: I also see you're calling Swing methods from the main thread, which is wrong. Swing calls should happen on the AWT-thread. As described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simply using too many `static` fields for no reason, which is making your class less extensible. Moreover the `PictureViewer` class extends `JFrame` and then inside it instead of using the same reference (on which you calling methods like `getContentPane().add(scrollPane)`) you are instead creating a new `static` reference by using `PictureViewer viewer = new PictureViewer()`, how can they both be on the same instance.

Moreover, in order to change the background of `JScrollPane` simply do this thingy :

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Here is your modified code, though I never went deep into it to rectify all bad practices, though I did managed to bring few of them :-)

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class PictureViewer {
    class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            pauseViewer = !pauseViewer;
        }
    }

    class QuitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stopViewer = true;
            pauseViewer = true;
            setNextToView();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static Double height;
    static final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    static boolean pauseViewer = false;
    static Dimension screensize = new Dimension();
    static boolean stopViewer = false;
    static JFrame viewer;
    static Double width;

    JLabel area = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
    int currentPic = 0;
    File dir = new File(".");
    BufferedImage image;    
    String path;
    Action pauseAction;
    int pauseTime = 5;
    Action quitAction;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area,  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    ArrayList<File> thesePictures;

    private void displayGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        viewer = new JFrame("Picture Viewer");
        viewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        viewer.setUndecorated(true);  //Remove the minimize, maximize and close buttons entirely.

        //Get the list of files to display.
        initialize();

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponents();
        viewer.setPreferredSize(screensize);

        //Display the window.
        viewer.pack();
        viewer.setVisible(true);

        //Start showing pictures.
        while (!stopViewer) {
            try {
                showPictures();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Perform cleanup
        setNextToView();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PictureViewer().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void addComponents() {
        //Set up actions.
        pauseAction = new PauseAction();
        quitAction = new QuitAction();
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "doPauseAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doPauseAction", pauseAction);
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doQuitAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doQuitAction", quitAction);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        viewer.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getPictures(File dir) {
        ArrayList<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
        int selectThis = (int) (Math.random() * listFiles.size());
        boolean emptyList = true;

        if (listFiles.get(selectThis).isDirectory()) {
            return getPictures(listFiles.get(selectThis));
        } else {
            //if the selected file is not a directory, go through the list of files and remove any directories.

            ArrayList<File> newList = new ArrayList<File>();

            for (File thisFile : listFiles) {
                if (!thisFile.isDirectory() && !thisFile.getName().contains(".next") && !thisFile.getName().contains(".jar")) {
                    newList.add(thisFile);
                }
            }

            listFiles = newList;
        }

        return listFiles;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        height = screensize.getHeight();
        width = screensize.getWidth();
        String filePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        filePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.length() - 1);
        String directory = "";

        while (thesePictures == null || thesePictures.size() == 0) {
            thesePictures = getPictures(dir);
        }

        String absolutePath = thesePictures.get(0).getAbsolutePath();
        path = absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));

        //Look to see if the .next file exists.  If so, read in the file object.  If not, set the index to 0.
        File checkFile = new File(path + "\\.next");

        if (checkFile.exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(path + "\\.next");
                InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(inputFile);
                ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
                File lastViewedPic = (File) input.readObject();

                if (thesePictures.contains(lastViewedPic)) {
                    currentPic = thesePictures.indexOf(lastViewedPic);
                } else {
                    currentPic = 0;
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Look at " + path + "\\.next");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        } else {
            currentPic = 0;
        }
    }

    public void readInFile(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.isFile()) {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(file);

                if (image.getWidth() > width || image.getHeight() > height) {
                    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width.intValue(), height.intValue(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width.intValue(), height.intValue(), null);
                    g.dispose();
                    image = newImage;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessageDialog(viewer,"Does not compute !","No file read or found",INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showMessageDialog(viewer, "Problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setImage(JLabel area){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        area.setIcon(icon);
        viewer.repaint();
    }

    protected void setNextToView() {
        //See if the next picture to view file exists.  If not, create it.
        File checkFile = new File(path + "\\.next");

        if (!checkFile.exists()) {
            try {
                checkFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\.next");
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(outputFile);
            writer.writeObject(thesePictures.get(currentPic));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showPictures() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!pauseViewer) {
            //If we reach the last file in the directory, switch to another directory (it could be the same directory).
            if (currentPic + 1 == thesePictures.size()) {
                currentPic = 0;
                thesePictures = new ArrayList<File>();

                while (thesePictures == null || thesePictures.size() == 0) {
                    thesePictures = getPictures(dir);
                }
            } else {
                currentPic += 1;
            }

            readInFile(thesePictures.get(currentPic).getAbsolutePath());
            setImage(area);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(pauseTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine on command prompt, though like I said before, I never did went deep into the whole code, to drag out all bad practices :-) Still cannot say regarding `JAR`, let me have my dinner, then will try that, and update you on how it goes, on my side :-)

Comment: @MichaelRobinson : Well it is working fine, if I create the `JAR` file manually, though, cannot say about Eclipse now. Though I can add steps to create `JAR` manually if you like, to test that yourself !!! Or you can check this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07h2w16th81zovg/GurOihQoyL), where I had added everything.

Comment: Well, I can get my jar file to work if I take out the Runnable stuff, so I am good to go.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson : No, no, you be doing the __biggest mistake__, if you take out the best part, that your code missed :-) Please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), for more information on this :-). For the rest you're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36408/discussion-between-michael-robinson-and-nice-cow)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the background color of the `scrollPane` component.  You're attaching the scroll pane to the content pane and then setting the background color of the content pane, but the scroll pane is covering the content pane so you can't see the background of the content pane.

**Edit**:

I've looked over your full class and found a confusing part.  This is all enclosed in the `PictureViewer` class but you're also accessing static instances of a `PictureViewer viewer;`. Looking at your method again:

```
 public void addComponents() {
        //Set up actions.
        pauseAction = new PauseAction();
        quitAction = new QuitAction();
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "doPauseAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doPauseAction", pauseAction);
        scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doQuitAction");
        scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doQuitAction", quitAction);
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        viewer.repaint();
    }
```

You're adding the `scrollPane` component to `getContentPane().add(scrollPane)` but the call to `getContentPane()` will return the content pane of the `this` instance and not the static `viewer` instance.  Give this a shot:

```
public void addComponents() {
            //Set up actions.
            pauseAction = new PauseAction();
            quitAction = new QuitAction();
            scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "doPauseAction");
            scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doPauseAction", pauseAction);
            scrollPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doQuitAction");
            scrollPane.getActionMap().put("doQuitAction", quitAction);
            scrollPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            viewer.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

            viewer.repaint();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The scrollpane will display the component you "focused" it on, and it will use a JViewPort as a background.

Anyway, the short story is that you have two options:

#### First one:

make both the scrollPane and the viewport non-opaque:

```
 getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
 scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
 scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

#### Second one:

set the background of your viewport:

```
 scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
```

---

Even though it's more complex, I prefer the first one, because it's conceptually more correct, in that the background of the frame is actually black.
Here is the sample frame I used to try:

```
//imports...

public class ColoredFrame extends JFrame {

    public ColoredFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
        JLabel area = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        JScrollPane scrlPane = new JScrollPane(area, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrlPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrlPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        add(scrlPane);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frm = new ColoredFrame();
                frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frm.setSize(500,500);
                frm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: +1, exactly what I posted, though seems like you came ahead of me on this :-)

Comment: Just one advice, do not use `frm.doLayout()` directly, as [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#doLayout()) also point out, instead use `validate()` :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot that. I used it because I just wanted it to layout to be able to check the component at arbitrary coordinates. Those lines should have been removed. I'm doing that now.